# Update template with model changed from input vueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'm developing my first app in vueJs and laravel.
now I 'have a problem with `v-model`.
I have a page with component **Person** that edit or create new Person.
So I get from my backend in laravel or Model Person or new Person.

Now in my frontend I pass data to component by props:

**Page.blade.php**

```
<Person :person-data="{!! jsonToProp($person) !!}"></Person>
```

(jsonToProp transform model coming from backend in json)
In this case, I would return new Model so without properties, so **$person** will be a empty object.

**Person.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    <label for="name_p"> Name</label>
    <input id="name_p" v-model="person.name" class="form-control" />
    <button v-on:click="test()">test</button>
    {{person.name}}
</div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
        props: ['personData'],
        mounted() {
        },
        data() {
            return {
                person: this.personData
            }
        },
        methods:{
          test(){
             console.log(this.person.name);
          }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Now if I change input with model `v-model="person.name"` I would print name in template but it doesn't change.
But if I click buttonit console write right value.
So I read that changing model value is asynch, so How I can render new Model when change input?

Comment: I would suggest in `created` that you check to make sure all the properties you *need* are on the `personData` object, and *if not*, initialize them using [$set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set).

Comment: Thankyou, but it mean that if I have for example 30 properties I should declare 30 property in created? :/

Comment: The issue is that you are adding properties dynamically to an empty object. You can either start with an object that already has those properties or add them properly if you want them to be reactive.

Comment: Ok, I understand! thankyou! Now it Work, I have created my object from backend and in frontend I already have the correct properties that are reactive. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare all the properties up front, as per the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating):

> **Why isn’t the DOM updating?**
>
> Most of the time, when you change a Vue instance’s data, the view updates. But there are two edge cases:
>
> 1. When you are **adding a new property** that wasn’t present when the data was observed. Due to the limitation of ES5 and to ensure consistent behavior across browsers, Vue.js cannot detect property addition/deletions. The best practice is to always declare properties that need to be reactive upfront. In cases where you absolutely need to add or delete properties at runtime, use the global `Vue.set` or `Vue.delete` methods.
> 2. When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. `arr[0] = val`) or modifying its `length` property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method `arr.$set(index, value)` which is just syntax sugar for `arr.splice(index, 1, value)`.

Comment: Thankyou, but it mean that if I have for example 30 properties I should declare 30 property in created? :/ –

Comment: You can have a look [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). You could use `$set` or `Object.assign` with a new object.

Comment: Yes I saw, the problem is that i wouldn't reconstruct the object manually in frontend, but I 've resolved with backend and now it Work.
Thankyou for reference!

Comment: Just a friendly reminder, Nora, even though you're linking to documentation (and such links are *less* likely to rot), it's always recommended on Stack Overflow that you [include the essential parts of the information from the link in your answer itself](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259). I've done that for you already here, in response to a flag.

Answer (score 0):

That may be because your data, which comes from `jsonToProp($person)` does not reactive.
You see, vue modify each object to make it 'reactive', some times you need to modify it by your own. [detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)
Try to do `this.person = Object.assign({}, this.person, this.personData)` in your mounted hook, to make it reactive.

Comment: This is the right idea, but if `this.personData` is an empty object as the question suggests, it won't help.